# Need to split a string and count occurrence

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a string in my `ViewData`. I need to split it be `COMMA` and count the occurrence of words.

```
i.e. ViewData["words"] = "apple,orange,grape".
```

I need to split and get the answer as 3.

Comment: I hope you see this question is not specific to ASP.NET and ViewData.

Answer (score 2):

The function `Split` converts a string to an array of strings. 
If we have `string a="hello,bill,gates";`, and call the function `Split` on it
`string[] b = a.Split(',');`, the value of `b` becomes `{"hello", "bill", "gates"}`.
Then, the number of elements is counted with `Length`:

```
int count = ViewData["words"].Split(',').Length;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `split` method:

```
int count = ViewData["words"].Split(',').Length;
```